# Should questions about financial projections be off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Financial projections can be considered part of PM discussion in PM SE? I´m not sure if it is directly related to project or financial issues (there is another site that handles financial Q&A?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that as long as the question is related to managing *project* finances/budgets then it should be okay. Money is a resource that needs to be managed and is often (always?) a constraint that needs to be considered in project management. [Cost management](http://www.slideshare.net/YudhaPratama17/pmp-pmbok-5th-edition-chapter7-project-cost-management) is also one of the PMBOK knowledge areas. That said, if the question were about pure financial management (like, how should VAT be applied in a particular scenario) then it might veer off-topic.